# Simulating Field-visibility problem in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

I was going through one of the tutorials on memory model of Java and came across this concept of `field visibility` which happens in multi-threaded programming. I tried to simulate the same using the below code, however , I see in each thread, the latest value is being reflected (in ReaderThread).

The below is the complete program.

### Edit

After some suggestion to use while(somevariable), I incorporated, but still getting the same behaviour. I removed sysout on reading the `x`

**FieldVisibility.java**

```
package com.example.threads.fieldvisibility;

public class FieldVisibility {

    private int x;

    private boolean condition;

    public FieldVisibility() {
        condition = true;
    }

    public void reader() {

        System.out.println("x in reader() is " + x);
    }

    public void writer() {
        x++;

    }

    public boolean getCondition() {
        return condition;
    }

    public void setCondition(boolean condition) {
        this.condition = condition;
    }
}
```

**ReaderThread.java**

```
package com.example.threads.fieldvisibility;

public class ReaderThread extends Thread {

    private FieldVisibility fv;

    public ReaderThread(FieldVisibility fv) {
        this.fv = fv;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (fv.getCondition()) {

            System.out.println("It mean condition is true, which was set initially");

        }
        for (;;) {

        }
    }
}
```

**WriterThread.java**

```
package com.example.threads.fieldvisibility;

public class WriterThread extends Thread {

    private FieldVisibility fv;

    public WriterThread(FieldVisibility fv) {
        this.fv = fv;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        fv.setCondition(false);
        for (;;) {

            fv.writer();
        }

    }
}
```

**MainApp.java**

```
package com.example.threads.fieldvisibility.main;

import com.example.threads.fieldvisibility.FieldVisibility;
import com.example.threads.fieldvisibility.ReaderThread;
import com.example.threads.fieldvisibility.WriterThread;

public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        FieldVisibility fv = new FieldVisibility();

        ReaderThread rt = new ReaderThread(fv);
        WriterThread wt = new WriterThread(fv);

        wt.start();

        rt.start();

        Thread.sleep(999999999L);
    }
}
```

### Edit

I added a new variable `condition` in `FieldVisibility`, whose default values is `true`. Next, I set its value to `false` in `WriterThread`, however, the same value (false) is still propagated to `ReaderThread`, so I still am not able to simulate it.

**Original**
I expected that at some time `ReaderThread` won't be able to "see" the latest value of variable `x`, but I saw every time I run it, it gave same results. I even run in debug mode, suspended `ReaderThread` while running `WriterThread` continuously.  But that also didn't prevent `ReaderThread` to have latest values. I expected that I need to declare variable `x` as volatile in order for `ReaderThread` to read latest values of `x`.

How can I simulate the `field visibility` concept, or what changes I need to do for this?

Comment: `System.out.println()` will synchronize with other calls to `System.out.println()`.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn: Can you please suggest how to simulate it? Where do i need changes?

Comment: Try to do `while (someField);` in one thread, and then change `someField` to false in an other thread after a while.

Comment: Check out [jcstress](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/CodeTools/jcstress) tool. [Here](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jcstress/file/7dce6af27fd5/jcstress-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jcstress/samples/APISample_01_Simple.java) is a simple example of using it

Comment: @JohannesKuhn: I added someField ( I hope I understood you, however still not able to simulate :-(

Comment: See my answer. If you want to see such effects, try to do them in isolation. Adding `System.out.println()` statements will likely mess up the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example doesn't work because `System.out.println()` uses a shared resource (`System.out`), so it will synchronize with other uses of the same resource.

Therefore you will never* see a result where one thread uses the old value of the other. (*in theory it is possible for the reader to read `x` between `x++` and the corresponding `System.out.println()`

Here is an example where a old value is used:

```
public class ThreadVisibility implements Runnable {

    private boolean stop = false;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!stop);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ThreadVisibility test = new ThreadVisibility();
        Thread t = new Thread(test);
        t.setDaemon(true);
        System.out.println("Starting Thread");
        t.start();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("Stopping Thread");
        test.stop = true;
        t.join(1000);
        System.out.println("Thread State: " + t.getState());
    }
}
```

If you run this code, it will display that the thread is still running at the end. Without the `t.setDaemon(true)`, the VM would wait for the Thread to finish, which would never happen.

If you comment out the `Thread.sleep`, then the new Thread may terminate (at least it did in my tests), but it is not guaranteed to.
The right fix for this problem is to declare `stop` `volatile`.
Or add a memory barrier.

Comment: Thanks for providing the code sample, it works. I have two follow ups: 1) What is `memory barrier` and 2) you initially wrote `System.out.println()` will synchronize with other calls to `System.out.println()`. I wasn't aware of this concept at all. Can you add a bit on these two point? I will of course, do some research on these concepts.

Comment: Memory barrier or memory fences are low level operations that tell the Compiler/CPU not to reorder read and/or writes before the fence with read or writes after the fence. In java they are accessible through the static [`VarHandle`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/VarHandle.html) methods, but are an advanced topic. `System.out.println()` uses synchronization internally to ensure only one thread writes to the output at the same time. So from the outside view, it may do synchronization with other calls. (If you redirect it, it might not do that)