# Thread.sleep causes spin loop to loop forever

Tags: java, java-14

Consider the following code:

```
public class Example {

  @SneakyThrows
  private static VarHandle init() {
    MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
    return lookup.findStaticVarHandle(Example.class, "x", int.class);
  }

  private final static VarHandle X = init();
  private static int x;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
      System.out.println("Gonna wait till x becomes 1");
      while ((int) X.get() != 1) ;
      System.out.println("x is now 1");
    });
    thread.start();
    new Thread(() -> {
//      System.out.println("Sleeping for 1 second");
//      sleep(1000); // uncomment this statement to reproduce
      X.set(1);
    }).start();
    thread.join();
  }

  @SneakyThrows
  public static void sleep(long ms) {
    Thread.sleep(ms);
  }
}
```

When I uncomment `sleep(1000);` statement and recompile it back to run it, the program loops forever. Now to solve this problem, I can use `Thread.onSpinWait();` after the `while((int) X.get() != 1)` but I am really interested in understanding why does the program does this in the first place?

Note: `@SneakyThrows` is from lombok and is there to make the code easy to read. It's just like a normal try-catch block.

Comment: By "halt forever" do you mean "loop forever"?

Comment: `X.get()` does not have any ordering grantee. The JIT will most likely rewrite the code as `int __tmp = x; while (__tmp != 1);`, looping forever. Use `X.getOpaque()`. Also see my answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58041588/simulating-field-visibility-problem-in-java/58041789#58041789)

Comment: I admit that I've never touched `VarHandle`s, but generally speaking if you're dealing with a variable cross-threads, you want a volatile variable... and it just so happens that `VarHandle`s have `.getVolatile` and `.setVolatile` methods to replicate this behavior.

Comment: Depends on the exact use case. If you want to wait until an other thread has produced something, `.setRelease()` and `.getAquire()` are good enough.

Comment: @Powerlord Indeed, for the safety. Some maintainer might just mess up with the semantics otherwise. Anyways, Johannes is right about the ordering.