# Java - while(true) loop not checking, if condition is true, if the else statement is missing

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

```
public class Main {

    public static boolean isToggled = false;
    public static boolean isClicking = false;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        while(true){
            if(Main.isToggled && Main.isClicking){
                System.out.println("Running");
            }            
        }
    }
```

I have two public static booleans with the value of false in my Main class.

A while(true) loop will constantly check, if both booleans are set to true, by another class.

However, if both conditions are being set to true, nothing happens.

The while loop only works, if an else statement is added to it like this:

```
public class Main {

    public static boolean isToggled = false;
    public static boolean isClicking = false;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        while(true){
            if(Main.isToggled && Main.isClicking){
                System.out.println("Running");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Idle");
            }            
        }
    }
```

So it is definitely the while loop that is the problem.

The class which sets the conditions to true works perfectly fine. I've tested that by removing the while loop, and just printing the value of the booleans after their value has changed.

I don't understand, why the first code isn't doing what its supposed to, when the other one with the else statement added to it does.

Copy code to test:

```
public class Main {

    public static boolean isToggled = false;
    public static boolean isClicking = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread changeBoolsT = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                changeBools();
            }
        });
        changeBoolsT.start();


        while(true){
            if(isToggled && isClicking){
                System.out.println("OK");
                break;
            }
            else{ // Remove this else statement
                System.out.println("Waiting");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void changeBools(){
        try{
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        isToggled = true;
        isClicking = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are doing but the name of your boolean varibales make me think you should use a listener instead

Comment: Does this answer your question? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58041588/simulating-field-visibility-problem-in-java/58041789#58041789)

Comment: @xthe_white_lionx i am using a listener to check for key presses, to then change the boolean values. in my main class i just want to check if the booleans have been set to true, to then execute another task

Comment: @JohannesKuhn im not sure if that helps me, its not the threading that is the problem, the code below is just an example. I just cant figure out why the very first code isnt working but the second is, where the only thing changed is that there has been an else statement with another sysout added to it.

Comment: Yeah, sysout synchronizes. Without synchonization it will read the old value.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Thanks, declaring the booleans as volatile did actually work!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JVM will optimize your code, because the value is never changed in your main thread. There is no synchronization happening between threads. You need to use `synchronized` blocks when reading and writing the variables or mark them as `volatile`. `volatile` will force them to be read anew from memory every time they are accessed.

Answer (score -1):

I dont think its your loop, its that you are trying to access static variables within your main method. A solution would be to instantiate a main object in your main class.

```
Main mainObj = new Main();
```

then your while look like

```
while(true){
     if(mainObj.isToggled && mainObj.isClicking){
            System.out.println("Running");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Idle");
        } 
}
```

Comment: This way should allow you to set your variables as private in order to adhere to good coding practices.

Comment: but i need the variables to be public static, so that they can be accessed in another class to change their values. the code below was just an example

Comment: Could you make a Main object member in the other classes. Instantiate the Main object in the main class, then use a setter method in your other classes to set the Main object in your main class to those classes.